# What is the reverse of Character.getNumericValue

Tags: java

```
    int x = Character.getNumericValue('A');
    System.out.println(" the value of x is:  " + x); // prints 10
```

I am looking for a method that takes in `somemethod(10)` and returns 'A'. Does such a method exist in java ?

Comment: `getNumericValue` doesn't produce a one-to-one mapping; a unique inverse doesn't always exist.

Comment: > The letters A-Z in their uppercase ('\u0041' through '\u005A'), lowercase ('\u0061' through '\u007A'), and full width variant ('\uFF21' through '\uFF3A' and '\uFF41' through '\uFF5A') forms have numeric values from 10 through 35. This is independent of the Unicode specification, which does not assign numeric values to these char values.

Comment: System.out.println(" the value of x is:  " + Character.getNumericValue('A')); -- it is giving me 10

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Thanks, too early in my morning :|

Comment: Consider `Character.forDigit(int, int)` that the docs for `getNumericValue()` also link to. Using `System.out.println(Character.forDigit(10, 11));` will print `a` (although I don't know what the purpose of *radix* is, you'll have to find this out yourself. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#forDigit(int,%20int)

Comment: But to answer your implied question, `Integer.toString(intVal, radix)` would be the approximate reverse.

Comment: (Though now that it's pointed out `Character.forDigit` is probably a better choice.)

Comment: @jeroen base-11 math? Presumably op wants 16 for hex.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: yeah, I found it after the 5minute grace period. The requirement for the radix was that it is bigger than the value itself. Value `10` will return `a` with any radix from `11` to `36`.

Comment: Character.forDigit is problematic if the code point cannot be represented by a single char.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Anubian Noob and Jeroen Vannevel, `Character.GetNumericValue('A') = 10`, `Character.GetNumericValue('a') = 10` and `Character.forDigit(10, 36) ='a'.

So IMHO, what is closest of what you ask would be

```
Character fromNumericValue(int x) {
    if ((x < 0) || (x > 35)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return Character.toUpperCase(Character.forDigit(x, 36));
}
```

It works for numbers between 0 and 9, returning chars '0' to '9', and for numbers between 10 and 35 returning letters 'A' to 'Z'. But I cannot imagine how you will use it.

Comment: If you are only interested in 0-9 A-Z this will work. However, if you want to use code points which require a surrogate pair, this will not work.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903008/what-is-a-surrogate-pair-in-java

Comment: @BrettOkken Beware, OP asked about `getNumericValue` which is **not** the same as code point. For example numeric value so 'a' and 'A' is 10 whereas code point of 'A' is 65 and code point of 'a' is 97