# Difference between codePointAt and charCodeAt

Tags: javascript, string, codepoint

What is the difference between `String.prototype.codePointAt()` and `String.prototype.charCodeAt()` in JavaScript?

```
'A'.codePointAt(); // 65
'A'.charCodeAt();  // 65
```

Comment: [MDN: charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) - first paragraph.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

From the MDN page on [`charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt):

> The `charCodeAt()` method returns an integer between `0` and `65535` representing the UTF-16 code unit at the given index.
>
> The UTF-16 code unit matches the Unicode code point for code points which can be represented in a single UTF-16 code unit. If the Unicode code point cannot be represented in a single UTF-16 code unit (because its value is greater than `0xFFFF`) then the code unit returned will be the *first part of a surrogate pair* for the code point. If you want the entire code point value, use [`codePointAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt).

#### TLDR;

- **`charCodeAt()`** is **UTF-16**
- **`codePointAt()`** is **Unicode**.

Comment: Just to add on, many unicode tables show hex values, e.g. U+00A0. Since `codePointAt` returns an int, you may want to convert it to hex by calling `.toString(16)` if you are looking up the unicode table manually.

Answer (score 43):

To add a few for the ToxicTeacakes's answer, here is another example to help you know the difference:

```
"".charCodeAt(0).toString(16);//d842
"".charCodeAt(1).toString(16);//dfb7

"".codePointAt(0);//20bb7
"".codePointAt(1);//dfb7

console.log("\ud842\udfb7");//, an example of hexadecimal digits
console.log("\u20bb7\udfb7");//₻7�
console.log("\u{20bb7}");// an unicode code point escapes the "\ud842\udfb7"
```

[The following](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#String_literals) is the info about javascript string literals:

> "\uXXXX"
> The Unicode character specified by the four hexadecimal digits
> XXXX. For example, \u00A9 is the Unicode sequence for the copyright
> symbol.
>
> "\u{XXXXX}"
> Unicode code point
> escapes. For example, \u{2F804} is the same as the simple Unicode
> escapes \uD87E\uDC04.

see also [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/codepointat-method-string-javascript)

Comment: Great example, just what I was looking for! A couple questions: (i) Do you know why `codePointAt(1)` returns a value if the `codePointAt(0)` captures the "whole" code point? (ii) Do you know how `toLowerCase()` vs `toLocaleLowercase()` fits here? Do character sets like the one in your answer even have lower/upper case?

Comment: I think it's because it's still indexed by 16 bits. So the index is the same index interpreted by `String.prototype.charAt` and `String.prototype.charCodeAt`. [If there is no element at the specified position, undefined is returned. If no UTF-16 surrogate pair begins at pos, the code unit at pos is returned.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt#Description).
So at index 1, the 16th bit, there's no [surrogate pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Examples) at index range [1,2] so it becomes the broken character "\udfb7" ("�")

Answer (score 4):

#### Example in JS

On The example with strings and emojis, I am going to illustrate how things could go wrong when you do not know that some of the characters could consist of 2 code units. Some of the characters take up more than one code unit. Consider using `codePointAt()` over `charCodeAt()` or use the first one if you are sure that your characters lie in of between `0` and `65535` (**2<sup>16</sup>**)

[more about code units here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Code_unit)

```js
// charCodeAt() is UTF-16
// codePointAt() is Unicode

/* UTF-16 is generally considered a bad idea today */

const strings = ["o", "four", "to"];
const emojis = ["", ""];

function printItemsLength(arr) {
    for (const item of arr) {
    console.log(item, item.length);
  }
}

printItemsLength(strings);
console.log('================================');
printItemsLength(emojis);
console.log('================================');
console.log("i.charCodeAt(0)", "i".charCodeAt(0)); // 105
console.log("i.charCodeAt(1)", "i".charCodeAt(1)); // 105
console.log("i.codePointAt(0)", "i".codePointAt(0)); // 105
console.log('=============EMOJIS=============');
// getting the decimal (dec) by which you can find them

console.log('===========charCodeAt===========');
// "surrogate pair"
console.log(emojis[0] + '.charCodeAt(0)', emojis[0].charCodeAt(0)); // only half-character - 55357
console.log(emojis[0] + '.charCodeAt(1)', emojis[0].charCodeAt(1)); // only half-character - 55357

console.log('===========codePointAt===========');
console.log(emojis[0] + '.codePointAt(0)', emojis[0].codePointAt(0)); // 128014

console.log('===========charCodeAt===========');
// "surrogate pair"
console.log(emojis[1] + '.charCodeAt(0)', emojis[1].charCodeAt(0)); // only half-character - 55357
console.log(emojis[1] + '.charCodeAt(1)', emojis[1].charCodeAt(1)); // only half-character - 55357

console.log('===========codePointAt===========');
// full-character
console.log(emojis[1] + '.codePointAt(0)', emojis[1].codePointAt(0)); // 128095
console.log(emojis[1] + '.codePointAt(1)', emojis[1].codePointAt(1)); // will return lower surragate (non-displayable character)
// to find this emojis have a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_emoji.asp
```

as someone may have noticed I have tried to convert back from charcode to the emoji, and it did not work on one of the symbols (that is because it is not in range of UTF-16

#### Introduction to Unicode and UTF-16

*<sup>please skip this section if you already familiar with it</sup>*

> `Unicode` – is a set of characters used around the world; `UTF-16` -
> 00000000 00100100 for "$" (one 16-bits);11011000 01010010 11011111
> 01100010 for "" (two 16-bits)
> [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241348/what-is-unicode-utf-8-utf-16/27794229)

"surrogate pair" characters are emoji and some letters that consist of more than 1 character as it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15128103/6901693)

> The term "surrogate pair" refers to a means of encoding Unicode
> characters with high code-points in the UTF-16 encoding scheme. In the
> Unicode character encoding, characters are mapped to values between
> 0x0 and 0x10FFFF.
> [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5903080/6901693)

`Unicode` - It assigns every character a unique number called a **code point**.

#### Differentiating `charCodeAt()` from `codePointAt()`

`charCodeAt(pos)` returns code a code unit (not a full character).

If you need a character (that could be either one or two code units), you can use `codePointAt(pos)` to get its code.

`charCodeAt()` - returns an integer between 0 and 65535 representing the UTF-16 code unit at the given index [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)
`codePointAt()` - returns a non-negative integer that is the Unicode code point value at the given position [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt)

where `pos` is the index of the character you want to check.
Quote from the book:

> UTF-16 is generally considered a bad idea today. It seems almost
> intentionally designed to invite mistakes. It’s easy to write programs
> that pretend code units and characters are the same things.

[read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241348/what-is-unicode-utf-8-utf-16/27794229)

[jsfiddle sandbox](https://jsfiddle.net/UtmostCreator/7tosw6Lh/)
**Sources**:

1. [What is Unicode, UTF-8, UTF-16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241348/what-is-unicode-utf-8-utf-16/27794229)
2. Marijn Haverbeke *Eloquent JavaScript, 3rd Edition: A Modern Introduction to Programming* [Text] – City(not-specified) : No Starch Press, 2018 – 447 p. [can be found here](https://eloquentjavascript.net/)
3. [What is "surrogate pair"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903008/what-is-a-surrogate-pair-in-java)
4. to find this emojis have a look [w3schools.com/charsets/ref_emoji](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_emoji.asp)

Chapter 5, p. 91 => `Strings and character codes`