# charAt vs charCodeAt?

Tags: javascript, string

JavaScript provides `charAt` and `charCodeAt` methods on strings.

- What is the difference between these two methods?
- When would one use on over the other?

Comment: [rtfm - charAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) and [charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between codePointAt and charCodeAt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527642/difference-between-codepointat-and-charcodeat)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the MDN page on [**`charAt`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt)

> The [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) object's `charAt()` method returns a new string consisting of the single UTF-16 code unit located at the specified offset into the string.

From the MDN page on [**`charCodeAt`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt):

> The `charCodeAt()` method returns an integer between `0` and `65535` representing the UTF-16 code unit at the given index.
>
> The UTF-16 code unit matches the Unicode code point for code points which can be represented in a single UTF-16 code unit. If the Unicode code point cannot be represented in a single UTF-16 code unit (because its value is greater than `0xFFFF`) then the code unit returned will be the *first part of a surrogate pair* for the code point. If you want the entire code point value, use [`codePointAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt).

- If you need the char as a string, call `charAt`.
- If, for some reason, you need the UTF char code, call `charCodeAt`

  *(You could use it to increment the character for example.)*

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = 'ABC.................Z';
a.charCodeAt(0); // will return 65
a.charAt(0); // will return 'A'
```