# Why is my ASCII to string conversion producing unicode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ascii

The following is producing unicode, when it should be producing string?

```js
let str = "hello";

let string = []
for(let s in str){
  string.push(str.codePointAt(s))
}
console.log(string) // ASCII

let back = []
for(let s in string){
  back.push(String.fromCharCode(s))
}
console.log(back) // unicode??
```

Comment: A `for ... in` loop iterates through the **keys** of an object. Your loop is iterating through the character indexes of the string.

Comment: Most Likely this is the answer you are looking for.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527642/difference-between-codepointat-and-charcodeat

Comment: Also note that the argument to `.fromCharCode()` is the actual character code you want. You're just passing the index.

Comment: @samakshshrivastava I doubt that. The code in this question simply does not make sense.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527642/difference-between-codepointat-and-charcodeat

Answer (score 2):

`for (let s in string)` iterates over the *indices* of each element.  You're converting the numbers `0`, `1`, `2`, ... to characters and pushing them into a string.

This is evident if you either add a simple `console.log(s)` to your loop, or if you examine the output, where each element is clearly sequential starting from 0:

```
['\x00', '\x01', '\x02', '\x03', '\x04', '\x05', '\x06', '\x07', '\b']
```

Comment: Thanks - sometimes my eyes go crosseyed and I miss the obvious