# Is possible to create a Scala string that contains invalid UTF-8 bytes?

Tags: scala, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to test some code that uses [`scodec.bits.ByteVector`](http://scodec.org/api/scodec-bits/1.0.12/#scodec.bits.ByteVector$).

In particular I'm using `ByteVector.encodeUtf8(str: String): Either[CharacterCodingException, ByteVector]`

Since this can return an potential error if encoding to UTF-8 fails, I have to handle the error condition. Of course, I can hide the call and mock my trait so that I forcibly return a `Left[CharacterEncodingException]` but that's too onerous.

What I would love to do is to create a `String` that has some invalid utf-8 bytes and call `encodeUtf8` with that.

My guess is that this is not possible. No matter what I do, String class will coerce any bad entries into something that is nonsensical but is still valid UTF-8 (e.g. �). Is this right?

This is how I've been trying to create such a string:

```
new String(Array(255.toByte), "utf-8")
```

I also tried to create a string in some other encodings and then use that to encode to UTF-8 but ByteVector handles it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"\uDC00"` is an invalid String that cannot be encoded in UTF-8. That's because it contains an unpaired [surrogate code point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903008/what-is-a-surrogate-pair-in-java).

Comment: Oh wow, excellent thank you! This does indeed work. ByteVector.encodeUtf8 returns a `Left(java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1)`