# Char replacing in java

Tags: java

I have a file path like this

```
\\ptrisf02\group\Corrolog\Other\Newfolder\SecurityTest\EV10222-01\FinalPack\REP WI\3101384589-(PN-5A1662).pdf
```

I want to replace `\\` to  `\\\\` and `\` to `\\` . I wrote this code for it

```
String r_Docpath=Docpath.replace('\\', '\\\\');
```

But it gives **Invalid character constant** error. How can I made it correctly?

I solved the problem like this codes;

```
String r_Docpath=Docpath.replace("\"", "\\\"");
String r2_Docpath=r_Docpath.replace("\\", "\\\\\"");
```

Comment: I sense an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  Why would you want to change each backslash to two backslashes?  Clearly, the path is valid as it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java `'` is used to create `char` literal which can represent only *one* character (`char` is type which holds 16 bits and JVM uses UTF-16 encoding so it can store only one character - or even half in case of characters created via [surrogate-pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903008/what-is-a-surrogate-pair-in-java)). So when you write `'\\\\'` it is like writing `'ab'` which as you see is attempt to place two characters in single `char` literal, which causes compiler to complain.

To group *zero or more* characters in one structure we use String type. You can create String literal with `"` instead of `'`.

So what you are after seems to be

```
String r_Docpath = Docpath.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

---

BTW you shouldn't name variables starting with upper-case in Java, so instead of `Docpath` use `docpath` or even `docPath`. Style like `Docpath` or `DocPath` where first character is uppercase is reserved for classes, interfaces, enums like `String` `List` `TimeUnit` etc.

Comment: Good Answer. I would add a note that `char` type is now outmoded, as it cannot represent all Unicode characters. Instead we use integer numbers as [code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point).