# UTF8 Character Malformed in CKEditor

Tags: utf-8, ckeditor

When trying to save:

in CKEditor with:

```
&#119868;
```

it gets converted to:

```
&#55349;&#56380;
```

if the source is viewed. If the source is then closed out this gets converted to:

```
&#65533;&#65533;
```

or as source data:

��

I tried another solution to set the character set on the library call but that hasn't resolved the issue.

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="/lib/CKEditor/ckeditor.js>
```

Is there another solution to this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a "surrogate pair" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903008/what-is-a-surrogate-pair-in-java)

Comment: That explains the first conversion but not the second, nor how to resolve it. This is in a WYSIWYG editor... or I've misread one of the answers on that question?